# Searching through a string in a database for a '_' and then inputting a variable into it?

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I have a column in my MySQL db called 'questionwording' in this column I have stored questions with _ in the middle of them, where the _ are I want to put in random numbers (Stored in variables).

Is there a way I can loop through the question I get from the database and then input the variables into the places where an _ is? Thanks for any but i've been pretty stuck on this.

Comment: how are the random numbers generated? same for each row?

Comment: I've just done $randomnumber = rand(1,20); as they only need to be small numbers. I would prefer if each '_' had a different random number in if thats possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(col_question, '_', FLOOR(RAND() * 19)+1) AS new_question;
FROM 
    questionwording;
```

Comment: So this updates it in the database, can you not change anything in the database but just change it in php (so the question in the database isnt affected?).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're exactly asking but I would do this like so:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT questionwording, id FROM questions LIMIT 1;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$numbers = array("12", "18", "2");
while ($question = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $questionwording = $question['questionwording'];
    foreach ($numbers as $number) {
        $questionwording = preg_replace("~_~", $number, $questionwording, 1);
    }
}
echo $questionwording;
?>
```

Obviously where I echo the final result you can do an INSERT INTO query into your database.

Just seen that you want random numbers in your question, you should be able to do that yourself

Good luck!

Comment: @calumrobb Glad to hear it